# php .htaccess mod_rewrite problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

hi friends there is some problem i need to convert
http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_myblog 
to
http://localhost/joomla/blog through .htaccess
any help?

Comment: You should be able to find the answer to this with about 5 minutes of google searching.  What have you tried... and how did it not work?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? Convert URL w/ request variables to "SEO friendly" URLs?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, Joomla by default ships with an htaccess.txt file that contains all the necessary script to do that. You just need to rename the file to .htaccess and enable the "friendly url" option in your sites settings.

Comment: problem is that cant use native sef options or cant use sh404sef component because some inline images are broken just need to target 1 particular url by .htaccess which is defined above

Answer (score 0):

http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html ........ .htaccess should be in com_myblog folder other wise url mapping will not work like in noupe post it says URLs are Always Relative. problem solved thanks for anybody response